# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send in SOAP webservice

Tags: vb.net, web-services, wcf, service-reference

I have a reference to a webservice which uses SOAP to process the searches and starting today morning i am receiving the following error:

The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

This will not happen for few requests if the application is restarted and will start receiving these errors after a some time say like 5 minutes and if we restart as said the services are re-processed without any issues.

I have read: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/915599

but those methods will not work for my case. Anyone else have faced similar problem???

Comment: Did you use "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: Yes i did and i don't see where i can use  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3

Comment: Below, you say you used "Add Web Reference". Which one did you use?

Comment: I mean which command in Visual Studio did you use? Did you right click the project (or use the "Project" menu) and use the "Add Service Reference" command without clicking "Advanced" and then clicking the "Add Web Reference" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web Service host has changed their certificates and that was causing the web service to fail when trying to access the service. The host has provided me with the latest certificates and now the problem is resolved.

Its weird that that initial connection and subsequent requests worked once i restart the application until the connection is closed and then when the application re-tries to connect, that's when the error message is popping up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information to guarantee this will work, but this has happened to me before and the following solved the issue:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
```

Note that this will force SSL3 instead of TLS.  If the site you're hitting doesn't handle TLS well it could solve your problem. Note that all other HTTP/ServicePoint objects will then use SSL3 instead of TLS unless you change it back (including others in the same AppPool if this is IIS hosted).

Comment: I am using it in a windows forms application and i have added the reference using add web reference. I have checked the Reference.vb file but i couldnt see a place where i can use the above mentioned line